# Trying to sort this list of addresses numerically and alphabetically

Tags: python

I've managed to sort this list of addresses numerically, but my problem is that i'm trying to sort them numerically and alphabetically.

```
 address_list = ['100 Parker St, Springfield, MA','131 Parker St, Springfield, MA', '102 Boston Rd, Springfield, MA', '181 Boston Rd, Springfield, MA', '150 King St, Springfield, MA','103 King St, Springfield, MA']

address_list.sort()

for address in sorted(address_list):
    print(address)
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It appears you don't even need to implement `__eq__`. The below example works without implementing `__eq__`.

You can map each address to a separate class that implements `__lt__` and `__eq__` and then sort based on that. For example:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Text, Tuple


def parse_address(address: Text) -> Tuple[int, Text]:
    """I haven't extensively tested this yet.."""
    first_space = address.find(' ')
    if first_space == -1:
        raise ValueError('Invalid address')
    return int(address[:first_space]), address[first_space + 1:]


class CustomComparator(object):

    def __init__(self, address: Text):
        self._full_address = address
        self._number, self._address = parse_address(address)

    def __lt__(self, other: CustomComparator) -> bool:
        if self._number != other._number:
            return self._number < other._number
        return self._address < other._address

    # __str__ and __repr__ are just so printing appears cleaner in this case.

    def __str__(self) -> Text:
        return self._full_address

    def __repr__(self) -> Text:
        return str(self)


address_list = ['100 Parker St, Springfield, MA', '131 Parker St, Springfield, MA', '102 Boston Rd, Springfield, MA',
                '181 Boston Rd, Springfield, MA', '150 King St, Springfield, MA', '103 King St, Springfield, MA',
                '103 Boston Rd, Spingfield, MA']
address_list = [CustomComparator(address) for address in address_list]

address_list.sort()
print('\n'.join([str(address) for address in address_list]))
```

This will sort addresses first numerically then alphabetically. On this example it prints:

```
100 Parker St, Springfield, MA
102 Boston Rd, Springfield, MA
103 Boston Rd, Spingfield, MA
103 King St, Springfield, MA
131 Parker St, Springfield, MA
150 King St, Springfield, MA
181 Boston Rd, Springfield, MA
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by

> numerically and alphabetically

If you mean you want to sort 1st by number then by alphabet next to number and the number has fixed length (3 as in your example) `sorted` function do that automatically. If the number length is not not equal you can pad some extra zeros in front and use this as key for sorted function

```py
address_list = ['100 Parker St, Springfield, MA','13 Parker St, Springfield, MA', '102 Boston Rd, Springfield, MA', '18 Boston Ad, Springfield, MA','103 Boston St, Springfield, MA','103 Aing St, Springfield, MA', '150 King St, Springfield, MA','103 King St, Springfield, MA']

pad_zeros = lambda x: "0"*(6-len(x[1])) + x[1]+ " "
key = lambda s: re.sub("(^\d*)\s?", pad_zeros, s)

sorted(address_list, key=key)
```

**Output**

```
['13 Parker St, Springfield, MA',
 '18 Boston Ad, Springfield, MA',
 '100 Parker St, Springfield, MA',
 '102 Boston Rd, Springfield, MA',
 '103 Aing St, Springfield, MA',
 '103 Boston St, Springfield, MA',
 '103 King St, Springfield, MA',
 '150 King St, Springfield, MA']
```